# Issue In Infinity is not a valid double value as per JSON specification with float & Double object

Tags: java, javers

I am getting below error when object have value like Nan & Infinite

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinity is not a valid double value as per JSON specification. To override this behavior, use GsonBuilder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues() method.

I solved this using :-

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();

But with Javers when using 
javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff)

Its throwing the same error . How solve this .

I am not able to set . serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues property with Javers.

i am using "org.javers.core.Javers-5.1.3" library

Comment: Nan & Infinite  in Java?

Comment: Yes . I am getting Infinite value (Float & Double) in object .. How to handle this with Javers library with method (javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff))

Comment: Well, I didn't know that Java has Nan & Infinite, so there is no special support in Javers for them. Looks like this `serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()` should be called in Javers' JsonConverterBuilder. Consider contributing a PR.